# Unable to return results from JSON flat file with HTTP get call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am trying to remove a hardcoded array out of my code and into a flat file that I can replace at any time, so I am using HTTP get to do this.

With the code below it is not returning the structure in such a way that I can iterate over it in my markup. Also, for some reason when I look at Firebug and watch the requests it seems to make the call 4 times (!).

```
var app = angular.module('MainEventApp', ['cloudinary']);
app.service('MainEventRepository', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.$http = $http;

    this.getMainEvents = function () {
        return this.$http.get('/main_events.json').then(function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
}]);

app.controller("MainEventCtrl", ['$scope', 'MainEventRepository', function ($scope, MainEventRepository) {       
   $scope.main_events = MainEventRepository.getMainEvents();
}]);
```

> main_events.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "roman_numeral": "I",
        "name": "Hulk Hogan & Mr T vs Rowdy Roddy Piper & Paul Orndorff",
        "venue": "Madison Square Garden",
        "state": "New York",
        "attendance": 19121
    },
    ... and so on ...
]
```

My markup:

`ng-repeat='main_event in main_events'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, finish the promise:

```
MainEventRepository.getMainEvents().then(function(data) {
    $scope.main_events = data;
});
```

Also, in your service, return the `data` object from the response:

```
return response.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

THe `$http` call in your service returns a promise, so you need to do something like this in your controller:

```
MainEventRepository.getMainEvents().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.main_events = data;
});
```